# What's a simile/noun used to describe something shaking violently?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, simile

I'm looking for a simile or noun that can be used to describe something shaking violently. For example,

> The room shook as hard as --insert thing that shakes violently--.

Comment: Why is the room shaking? Earthquake?

Comment: Shakespeare gave us 'shook like a field of corn'. But I'm finding it hard to set aside 'quaked like a duck', which isn't absent when one searches. // 'Shaking like a leaf' is archetypical, but means 'quivering'.

Comment: @Cascabel A tornado

Comment: Hmmnnn....I have lived through several tornadoes and earthquakes, and there is a very different feeling between the two. A tornado slams a wooden building, but is rebuffed by concrete and brick, while an earthquake feels like walking on jello...even on concrete floors.

Comment: An incredibly nervous clam.

Comment: ... a freshly bathed dog

Comment: An off-balance washing machine on a fast spin.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the idiom *shake like a leaf* is suitable.

> **shake like a leaf**: [(thefreedictionary.com)](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/shake+like+a+leaf)
>
> To tremble violently with fear or nervousness.

Answer (score 0):

[Synonyms for shake violently](https://www.freethesaurus.com/shake):

1. **Churn** - Stir about, cause to froth; agitate violently; turn or throw up violently.

"Waves *churning* in the storm."

2. **Convulse** - Shake violently; agitate or disturb severely.

"Tremors that *convulsed* the countryside."

The idiom **shake like a leaf** is well known, but it's also a cliche. I'd avoid it.

Comment: I would also avoid "shake like a leaf, but mainly because it implies a weak trembling - something a room is unlikely to do.

Answer (score 0):

**rock**

> **To cause to shake violently**
> *An earthquake rocked the town.* [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rock)

> The earthquake rocked the building; the building rocked [Chambers](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Chambers_Universal_Learners_Dictionary/AB1f965CUnwC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22the%20earthquake%20rocked%22&pg=PA627&printsec=frontcover)

> It was an area of active volcanoes, and when the earthquake **rocked** his
> wooden house, he initially thought that it must be a nearby eruption.
> [ref](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Leadership_Dispatches/KFlpBgAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22the%20earthquake%20rocked%22&pg=PA20&printsec=frontcover).

This is clearly not another of this word's meanings, *to cause to sway back and forth,* as in *rock the cradle.*

You choice may depend on how violent the shaking is, any subtleties about the movement, and the size of the object: *...**bucked/wobbled/rocked** like an off-balance washing maching.*

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few examples, some perhaps more useful than others:

> The room shook as hard as...

- an old-time Quaker revival
- an addict in withdrawal
- a Volkswagen bus filled with hippies
- a Chihuahua in winter

Please forgive me...my sense of humor is a bit twisted. But maybe one of these will jog your creativity.

Comment: ELU deals solely with established (and verifiably so) usage.  Creative metaphors (if decent) would be welcome on Writing.SE.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, since the OP is asking for similes or metaphors, perhaps this question should be migrated to Writing.SE.

Comment: _Conventional metaphors_ (you include one example) and other fixed phrases are obviously fine on ELU. Not 'creative[/'poetic/'literary/'novel/'unconventional] metaphors'. (see [Nordquist](https://www.thoughtco.com/what-is-creative-metaphor-1689940#:~:text=A%20creative%20metaphor%20is%20an,novel%20metaphor%2C%20and%20unconventional%20metaphor.))

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, consider me suitably chastised.

Comment: Go and stand in the poets' corner for an hour.

Answer (score 0):

You could say ***shake like hell***, but note that it is informal:

> Some people use ***like hell*** to emphasize how strong an action or quality is.
>
> - I used to shake like hell. The Sun (2015) ([Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/like-hell))

It does remind you of the idea of *[all hell broke loose](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/all+hell+broke+loose)*.